# How do I generalize the nth term in an Arithmetic Progression?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, arithmetic-progressions

Sequence is $18, 14, 10,...$
So $n^{th}$ term is $18-4(n-1)$.
Now put $n=16$, it gives $-42$.
First term of the series is $18$ but $-42$ is the first term in the series that is a multiple of $21$.
If first term multiple of $21$ in this series is $-42$ then what is the $N^{th}$ term that is a multiple of $21$? 
I need a general way to find $N^{th}$ term that is a multiple of $21$.

Comment: If you find the next term, and the corresponding $n$, you might spot a clear connection between that $n$, $16$ and $21$. Try to see if that pattern continue, and you're on your way to a proof.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Please use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Comment: Arthur in this example I calculated -42 easily. What if we can't find it easily if we are dealing with big numbers scaling upto 10^999?  I am looking for a general way of finding nth term.

Comment: If you want to find a term that has a relation both as AP and GP, write two equations in terms of $N.M$ and solve for them.

Answer (score 1):

**HINT:** Notice that we are always subtracting $4$ so if $-42$ is the first term divisible by $21$, the other terms should be $-42-4k$ where $k$ is divisible by $21$ (If we know the first term divisible by $21$).

In order to find the first term (because after finding it, we can proceed as in the hint), define $a_n = 18-4n$, $n \in \mathbb{N}$. Then notice that all of the terms are even for this sequence so we can seek the first term divisible by $42$ instead of $21$. Say $18-4n = 42m$, where $n \in \mathbb{N}$ and $m \in \mathbb{Z}$. Here notice that since $n$ cannot be negative, $m$ must be negative or zero. It is easy to see that for $m=0$, $n$ is not a natural number so we can try it for $m = -1$ to see $n = 15$ and therefore $a_{15}$ is the first term divisible by $21$.

Comment: I appreciate your hint ArsenBerk. Your approach works if we already know the first term as -42 as in the example. But suppose we are unaware of first term that is divisible by 21 in that series and we are asked to tell the 1st or 5th or Nth term divisible by 21. Thats where I am stuck.

Comment: I edited my answer.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, the expression $18-4(k-1)$ will become cumbersome. So we simplify it to $22-4k$. Your sequence, then, is $t_k = 22-4k$. If you are looking for the terms that are multiples of $21$, then you have to solve

\begin{align}
   22-4k &\equiv 0 \pmod{21} \\
   4k &\equiv 22 \pmod{21} \\
   16 \cdot 4k &\equiv 16 \cdot 22 \pmod{21} \\
   k &\equiv 16 \pmod{21} \\
\end{align}

---

If you are not comfortable with congruence equations, you can try to solve

\begin{align}
   22-4k &= 21\ell \\
   4k+21\ell &= 22 \\
\end{align}

You found that $k=16$ is a solution. For that particular case, then, you can solve for $\ell$. $22-4(16) = 21\ell$ gives us $\ell=-2$. To find the general solution, we compare and subtract.

\begin{array}{c}
   4k     &+ &21\ell     &= 22 \\
   4(16)  &+ &21(-2)     &= 22 \\
\hline
  4(k-16) &+ &21(\ell-2) &= 0 \\
\end{array}

And so $4(k-16) = 21(2 - \ell)$. Since $4$ clearly divides $4(k-16)$, it must also divide $21(2 - \ell)$. Since $4$ and $21$ are relatively prime, then $4$ must divide $2-\ell$. Say $2-\ell = 4m$. And then

\begin{align}
   4(k-16) &= 21(2 - \ell) \\
   4(k-16) &= 21(4m) \\
   k-16 &= 21m
\end{align}

---

Either way, we get $k = 16 + 21m$ for all integers $m$. So the n$^\text{th}$ value of $k$ that gives you a multiple of $21$ is $k = 16 + 21(n-1)$ and
the n$^\text{th}$ number in your sequence that is a multiple of $21$ is

$22-4((16 + 21(n-1)) - 1) = 42-84n = 21(2-4n)$